# GitHub action to publish a path

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a build yaml file as follows:

```
jobs:
  XYZBuildAndRelease:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        BuildConfiguration:
        - debug
        - release
      max-parallel: 2

    runs-on: windows-2019

    steps:  
   
    - name: List contents of a folder
      run: dir

    - name: dotnet publish graph updater
      run: dotnet publish Service/XYZ/Hosts.FA/*.csproj --configuration Release --output updater_publish_output
```

On pushing this yaml file, I see the build failing -  Project file does not exist

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly specifiy the project to publish

```
- name: dotnet publish graph updater
  run: dotnet publish Service/GroupMembershipManagement/Hosts.GraphUpdater/Hosts.GraphUpdater.csproj --configuration Release --output updater_publish_output
```

Reason: you can't publish multiple projects at the same time, see https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7238.